# Difference between UglifyjsWebpackPlugin and UglifyJsPlugin

Tags: webpack-2

I am slightly confused about the difference between UglifyjsWebpackPlugin and UglifyJsPlugin.
Webpack 2 documentation talks about both of them in separate pages - 
1. https://webpack.js.org/guides/production-build/#minification
2. https://webpack.js.org/plugins/uglifyjs-webpack-plugin/

Second link also talks about dependency on git://github.com/mishoo/UglifyJS2#harmony for ES6 minification target.

Which one should I use in production (react app).

Answer (score 3):

1. `UglifyJsPlugin` is baked into webpack2 and uses that version of `uglify-js` that comes with webpack you use. So you can't change it's version without changing the webpack you use (in the current [master branch of webpack2](https://github.com/webpack/webpack/blob/master/package.json) `uglify-js` is `^2.x.x`).
2. [UglifyjsWebpackPlugin](https://webpack.js.org/plugins/uglifyjs-webpack-plugin/) uses that version of `uglify-js` that comes with your project (so you may install any version, stable or unstable, harmony or not).

Sources of [1](https://github.com/webpack/webpack/blob/87702a29ad798cd134ff5495ab57ceffe0fa6daf/lib/optimize/UglifyJsPlugin.js) and [2](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/uglifyjs-webpack-plugin/blob/7a9fd674d47630b779f51ffb1b90aee036c8eed6/src/index.js) are very close.

From [webpack2 documentation](https://webpack.js.org/plugins/uglifyjs-webpack-plugin/):

> Note that webpack contains the same plugin under webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin. This is a standalone version for those that want to control the version of UglifyJS.

---

> Which one should I use in production (react app)?

In production you may try using baked in UglifyJsPlugin as long as you transpile ES6 to something this plugin accepts.

Or there is also [Babili](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/babili-webpack-plugin) — a babel based minifier ready for ES6+ ([beta](https://github.com/babel/babili)).